# How to show the end scale value in the axis?

Tags: d3.js

Using d3.js v4, how to show the special scale value which can't be divide exactly?

For example: set the domain([0,24]), set the ticks(3). The value 24 don't show in the axis.

Please tell me how to show the value.

[image]

```js
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand()
          .rangeRound([0, width])
          .domain(['A', 'B', 'C'])
          .padding(0);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .domain([0, 24])
          .range([height, 0]);
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(3);
var svg = d3.select('#chart')
          .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .style('background-color', '#ecf0f1')
          .append('g')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        var g = svg.append('g');
        g.append('g')
          .attr('class', 'axis axis--x')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
          .call(xAxis);
        g.append('g')
          .attr('class', 'axis axis--y')
          .call(yAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<svg id="chart"></svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tickValues`, defining how many ticks you want with `scale.ticks()` and pushing the first and last domain values by concatenation with `scale.domain()`:

```
yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
    .tickValues(y.ticks(3).concat(y.domain()));
```

Check the updated snippet:

```js
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand()
          .rangeRound([0, width])
          .domain(['A', 'B', 'C'])
          .padding(0);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .domain([0, 24])
          .range([height, 0]);
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
.tickValues(y.ticks(3).concat(y.domain()));
var svg = d3.select('#chart')
          .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .style('background-color', '#ecf0f1')
          .append('g')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        var g = svg.append('g');
        g.append('g')
          .attr('class', 'axis axis--x')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
          .call(xAxis);
        g.append('g')
          .attr('class', 'axis axis--y')
          .call(yAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<svg id="chart"></svg>
```

Comment: I got it.Thank you very much!